# Swift iOS9 UIButton

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

This may be really easy but I am having a hard time trying to get this to work but essentially am trying to use a collectionview to make a grid-like format and also stick buttons inside each cell that play a sound.

This is what I have so far:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    var button = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
    button.setTitle(Array[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    return cell
}
```

And the array is basic but here it is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Array = ["apple","berries","dogs"]}
```

I've been trying to follow along this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH3HoPar_xg  @around 12 minutes-ish) but xcode is spitting back an error (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

All that I'm trying to do right now is change the button label to match what's in the array (then I'll focus on adding actions next). But are there any suggestions for the label? Do I have to make an outlet connections first? If so, why didn't the guy in the video have to do one? Let me know, I appreciate any help, thanks.

Forgot the mention - The button on the storyboard has a view set to 1.

Comment: I think you are not getting the `UIButton`. Try this `if let button = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton{
            button.setTitle(Array[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }`

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but it didn't work for me. Sorry, I should elaborate. It throws no errors but it doesn't change the title of the button

Comment: Try to print that value. Is value getting displayed in log?

Comment: It throws an error saying "use of identifier unresolved 'button'"

Comment: In example video `cell.viewWithTag(1)` is `UILabel`. Please check you'r code properly along with the tutorial.

Comment: He changes it later on after adding an additional button with a label. But regardless, that would be for a label, in the video, if you start from 12:37, he uses UIButton. But thanks for your help! I'll keep tinkering with it.

Comment: Why do you specifically need a button in the cell?  Since a cell is selectable, can't you simply play a sound when the user selects that cell?

Comment: in which line you are getting this error var button = cell.vi... or button.setTitle(.....

Comment: @Johnykutty i would probably say the first one, var button =cell causes it's throwing all sorts of errors from when I was playing around with it earlier.

Comment: @PetahChristian I didn't know that, I'm still learning through practice. I'll try that and let you know how it goes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following things are correct in your storyboard

1. The collectionView have a cell with identifier `CollectionViewCell`
2. The button in the cell have tag 1 and no other subviews have a tag 1